# Recommendation for jquery \ js physics engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, physics

I am building a small web based game, using html 5.
I need my game to work according to some simple physics.
Can you recommend from first hand of any  jquery \ js physics engine?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out Seth Ladd's 2011 Google I/O talk.  He shows how to build an HTML5 game (complete with sound), and makes reference to a number of good JS libraries.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEocRtn_j9s